# Challenge on ASCII Codes

Tags: ascii, non-ascii-characters, ascii-art, extended-ascii

My friend shared a challenge puzzle with me but i dont have any idea on this? I believe that its related to ascii characters

[image: Challenge Puzzle]

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, What i should do with this puzzle?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Try posting this on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Sure...let me try there!

Comment: Hey Hi , i have modified your code which was recent asked by you and it was deleted when I try answer ...........input is "-1 -1 1 -1 1 0 1 -1 -1" and it's output will be 7.........I thought to share that code to you, email to learneralways5@gmail.com

Comment: i sent you the mail bro

Comment: is that code which is modified working?

Comment: @KrisHJodu hope u got my mail?

Comment: @KrisHJodu, Please let me know the solution